# Is there a program that draws my signature with the mouse?

Tags: signature, drawing

So many website wants me to draw my signature with the mouse, and it's horrible. So I want a program that moves the mouse cursor and traces my signature.

The program would:

1. Ingest a JPEG of my signature.
2. Create a hot-key that, when pressed,
3. Has me rubber-band the rectangle for the signature area, then...
4. Move the mouse to follow the ingested signature with the mouse button down, making programs like DocuSign think that I'm actually singing my signature.

Is there anything like that for the Mac or iPhone?

Comment: Traces your signature from a photo, or something else?

Comment: Are you asking how to use Automator - watch me do function to record a signature and play back? It's not clear to me what "trace a signature" means - so perhaps editing this to elaborate if people don't answer in a couple weeks...

Comment: This program would combine analysis of the JPEG and control of the mouse using the automation API.